# trello oauth failed to redirect me to oauth_callback, and keeping redirect me to oob

Tags: java, redirect, oauth, trello

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333390/google-apps-script-oauth-connect-doesnt-work-with-trello), but it seems I still have this problem, I used

`https://trello.com/1/appKey/generate`

to generate my key and secret, and fill them into [scribe library](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/TrelloExample.java), the example seems right, but after I append

`&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fapi`

to

`service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken)`

trello keeping redirect me to something like

`https://trello.com/oob?oauth_token=7ad36dcd7ca713648ed3549c2f1828c5&oauth_verifier=5b0dc2b64d0b7ee08c56a9b1f30f8880`.

I'm not sure what I'm missing, does trello requires some application registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I finally figured it out, it's scribe library [example](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/TrelloExample.java#L17)'s fault that didn't make it clear: we should call callback and provide with callback to user's site before build the service

Comment: Taken directly from scribe's Getting Started: **The example uses OOB OAuth, if you want to pass a callbackUrl so that Twitter redirects you there just add a `callback("http://your_callback_url")` call before `build()`**

Comment: (downvoted: blaming the library and not reading the getting started)